# ocaml class object

Tags: ocaml

What does

```
self: #Arakoon_client.client
```

in this code means, and how to use such object

```
class remote_client ((ic,oc) as conn) =

object(self: #Arakoon_client.client)
```

Answer (score 6):

In many OO-languages, there is a keyword (`this` in C++) to refer to the object from within its methods. In OCaml, you can choose the name you want to use to refer to the object, by giving its name after the `object` keyword (here, they have chosen `self`).

In OCaml, you can also give a name to the parents from which a class inherits:

```
class x = object (self)
  inherit x_parent as parent
  method print = parent#print; print_newline()
end
```

For example, this can be used to use methods from an ancestor, that have been overridden by a method in the current class: in the previous example, `parent#print` calls the inherited method, while `self#print` would call the current method.

Finally, when you define a class `x`, you can refer the type of objects of this class using the `#x` notation. Here, `#Arakoon_client.client` refers to the type of objects of the class `client` defined in the module `Arakoon`.

Comment: I am still confused by the meaning of "#Arakoon_client.client"

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a value self which represents the object (instantiated) itself, and constraints openly by the type #Arakoon_client.client.

'object' must have all the methods of #Arakoon_client.client

Comment: What you mean by #Arakoon_client.client"? Is it like inherited too?

Answer (score 2):

In the [Arakoon_client](https://bitbucket.org/despiegk/arakoon/src/ada5840d1b78/src/client/arakoon_client.mli) module, there is a class type named `client`. The expression `Arakoon_client.client` refers to this type. As noted in @FabriceLefessant's answer, `self` refers to the object itself, and the expression after the colon the type to which the object must conform.

Finally, the `#` sign in front of the class typename indicates that the type is not closed (thus the "openly constraints" terms used by @Ontologiae) which means that `self` must support *at least* that interface, but may also hold other methods.

In other words, this is more or less the equivalent of `implements Arakoon_client.client` in java.